# DB - local to a friend

Tags: database

I want to duplicate my locally hosted website to a friend's environment. He says he needs a copy of website's database. I'm a bit of a an Drupal rookie so I have no clue of how do this. We are using a code base so all the other files are in there.

I check settings.php and it says I have mysql as the driver
I have drush and run the command

drush mysql-dump > random.sql

This didn't work. I got an error saying; the drush command mysql-dump could not be found.

Please follow me through the steps of how do this. I really need to sent share this website with my friend as quickly as possible.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by share website? And what does he mean by needing a database?

Comment: So he can view the entire site and run it local too. He told me I need to upload the database to the codebase. There is so many database files/folders. I dont know wihch on to upload...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To export your database, for example to migrate it, simplest option is to use [Backup and Migrate](https://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module.

> Back up and restore your Drupal MySQL database and files or **migrate a site between environments**. Backup and Migrate supports gzip, bzip and zip compression as well as automatic scheduled backups.

Emphasis mine.

To do it with **Drush**, use:

```bash
drush sql-dump > my-sql-dump-file-name.sql
```

You need to have `mysqldump` installed in your system. In Linux, it usually can be found in *mysql*, *mysql-client* or similarly named package, and installing it should take care about path configuration etc. In Windows, it's probably already in path like `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin` (depending on where you have installed it). Make sure to add that path to system's PATH variable (My Computer -> Properties or similar, depending on Windows version; look for "system variables", "environment variables", names like that).

Comment: sh: mysqldump: command not found
Database dump failed

Comment: @user2545642 what does it have to do with methods in my answer?

Comment: @Mołot `drush sql-dump` pretty much definitely uses `mysqldump` internally, which the OP doesn't appear to have installed.

Comment: @Clive oh, right. I'll update my answer. Anyway 1st part of my answer is still valid.

Comment: @Mołot It was already valid IMO :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the [Backup and Migrate](https://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module to achieve this. With this module, you can save your database as a ZIP-file via the Drupal `Configuration > System` interface and send it to your friend. He has to import the file and install it in his local database.